# Custom Make function doesn't get parameter

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to add Modules to my build system.

To keep my makefile clean when adding new modules, they all follow the same pattern, so I tried to generalize it with a function:

```
uc = $(shell echo $1 | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')

define driver-mod
$(eval CFLAGS += -DUSE_$(call uc, $1));
$(eval include $(DRIVERS_SRC)/$1/Makefile.include);
endef

ifneq (,$(filter led,$(USEMODULE)))
$(call driver-mod, led)
endif
ifneq (,$(filter uart,$(USEMODULE)))
$(call driver-mod, uart)
endif
ifneq (,$(filter button,$(USEMODULE)))
$(call driver-mod, button)
endif
```

(the `ifneq` is going to be replaced with a `$(foreach x, $(USEMODULE), $(call driver-mod, $(x))`

However, it seems like `$1` in driver-mod is not evaluated, I get

```
make: *** $(DRIVERS_SRC): Is a directory.  Stop.
```

(doesn't actually output `$(DRIVERS_SRC)` but it's value, edited for clarity)
When I replace the $1 with e.g. `led`, it works as expected.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have to escape the `$` for eval:

```
define driver-mod
$(eval CFLAGS += -DUSE_$(call uc, $1));
$(eval include $(DRIVERS_SRC)/\$1/Makefile.include);
endef
```

works!

Answer (score 0):

Can be simplified as follows:

```
uc = $(shell echo $1 | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')

define __driver-mod
    CFLAGS += -DUSE_$(uc)
    include $(DRIVERS_SRC)/$1/Makefile.include
endef

driver-mod = $(eval $(call __driver-mod,$(strip $1)))

$(foreach 1,$(USEMODULE),$(driver-mod))
```